# Is there a way to use Aggregation or $sum on dynamic embedded object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection with this structure:

```
{
  field1:'Foo',
  field2:11,
  stats:{
   A:10,
   B:15,
   C:10
 }
}
```

Now I want to sum up all the properties of the stats field.
But the stats field is Object and can be different from document to document(always only number fields, but the name of the fields can change),
so it can look something like this:

```
{
  field1:'Foo2',
  field2:12,
  stats:{
   A:10,
   B:10,
   D:5
 }
}
```

is there a way to use Aggregation or $sum  to get a result like this:

```
{
  sumStats:{
   A:20,
   B:25,
   C:10,
   D:5
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            stats: { $objectToArray: "$stats" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stats"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$stats.k",
            value: { $sum: "$stats.v" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            values: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$value" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$values" }
        }
    }
])
```

Since your keys are unknown you need [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to transform `stats` into a list of key value pairs. Then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get separate documents for each key-value pair. In the next step you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to aggregate values from all documents. As a result you want single object so you should group by `null` to accumulate all values in one object as a list of key-value pairs and then you can use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to obtain final structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the mapReduce aggregate.  Docs say it might be less efficient, but it is very easy to read (this is using Mongoose syntax, but it is just a thin wrapper over the function of the same name in the Mongo driver):

```
const mrd = {
  //creates an output bucket for each property in stats object
  map: function () { for (const prop in this.stats) emit(prop, this.stats[prop])},
  //sums all the values in the output bucket for each property
  reduce: function (k, vals) { return vals.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0)}
};

YourModel.mapReduce(mrd, function (err, results) {
  console.log(results)
  //something like this (ran at Mongo console, assuming Mongoose output is similar): 
  //[{ "_id" : "a", "value" : 20 },
  //{ "_id" : "b", "value" : 25 },
  //{ "_id" : "c", "value" : 10 }
  //{ "_id" : "d", "value" : 5 }
})
```

The output is not in one object, but that is easy enough to do in straight code (Array.mapReduce() for example);

Refs:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mapreduce_mapReduce
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/